# How do I provide API key when initializing Google Street View in JavaScript?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

"Static" [Street View documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) says that all request should have an API key added. There is also description how to add it. But looking at [JavaScript SV documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) there is no mentioning of API keys. Is using API keys with "dynamic" SV required? How do I add them to my requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required but you should according to Google:

> All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key. Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. If your application's Maps API usage exceeds the Usage Limits, you must load the Maps API using an API key in order to purchase additional quota.

Here is the link on using the [API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)